# Retrieve a list of files stored in a folder into my solution ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, tabular

I am not sure if I am in the right place to ask this, I am trying to create a table with all the PDF files that I have in a folder into my solution.

[image: Folder location screenshot]

And I am trying to retrieve their names and put them in a table to access all of them throughout a link.

I got the following method, however, it not working.

```
protected void ListFiles()
    {
        const string MY_DIRECTORY = @"~/HistoricalFiles";
        string strFile = null;
        foreach (string s in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(MY_DIRECTORY), "*.*"))
        {
            strFile = s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            //ListBox1.Items.Add(strFile);
        }
    }
```

Is there any way I can access all of them easily and display them in a good way?

Comment: What do you mean by *"not working"*? Is it throwing an exception? Does not find any files?

Comment: I meant, the method could not find the directory.

Comment: Can't you debug and get the value of **Server.MapPath(MY_DIRECTORY)** ? Verify that folder is the one you are expecting and that it actually exists

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your image, you should change the path of the folder. It is not in your root directory, it is inside `Reports\API` folder

```
const string MY_DIRECTORY = @"~/Reports/API/HistoricalFiles";
```